# Logging across a cluster

Tags: logging, hadoop, slf4j, apache-spark

I'm running a cluster based application (uses Spark, but same question applies to Hadoop) and would like to do application level logging (ideally using slf4j).  However, I want the logs to go to a central location - I don't want to have to read individual files on each machine.  A HDFS file would be great - or anything that I can pullback and grep in a single command.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a few ways to approach this problem. 
For rare / ad hoc searches tools like parallel SSH can be usable. Since log amount can be substantial parallel grep might be much more efficient
For monitoring - it makes sense to redirect logs (on error level) to systems like LogStash, capable to store and search large amounts of logs.